# Sql availability query error

Tags: mysql

I have a query to fetch the available rooms from 2 tables, `roomtypes` and `reservations`, as follows:

`Roomtypes` has the following columns

```
id,
product_id,
type,
total_no_of_rooms,
created_at,
updated_at
```

`Reservation` has the following columns

```
id, 
roomtype_id, 
customer_id, 
check_in, 
check_out, 
no_of_rooms, 
created_at, 
updated_at,
```

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms, 
    SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as "reserved rooms", 
    rt.total_no_of_rooms - SUM(r.no_of_rooms) as "rooms available"  
FROM Roomtypes rt 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations r ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
        AND '2018-04-11 10:00:00' >= r.check_in 
        AND '2018-04-12 09:59:59' <= r.check_out
GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

When there is a reserved room in the given date, the column shows values to rooms available and rooms reserved. But if no rooms are reserved, the column shows null as values where as I need to get the rooms available as number of rooms available and reserved rooms as 0. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following query (Considering you are using mysql):

```
SELECT rt.id, rt.type, 
    rt.total_no_of_rooms, 
    if(SUM(r.no_of_rooms) IS NULL,0,SUM(r.no_of_rooms)) as "reserved rooms", 
    (rt.total_no_of_rooms - if(SUM(r.no_of_rooms) IS NULL,0,SUM(r.no_of_rooms))) as "rooms available"
FROM Roomtypes rt LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservations r 
    ON r.roomtype_id = rt.id 
    AND '2018-04-11 10:00:00' >= r.check_in 
    AND '2018-04-12 09:59:59' <= r.check_out 
GROUP BY rt.id, rt.type, rt.total_no_of_rooms
```

I have just added condition to check `NULL` value. If you are using PostgreSQL, use `COALESCE` function.

Comment: how can i change it in such a way that i can use a range of dates or check btw 3 dates

Comment: `COALESCE()` works in all major DBMS prodcuts, not only Postgres. It's `IF()` that's proprietary.

Comment: am new to sql. can you edit the code and post it as an answer